# AJAX Form Example for a N00b

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I will begin with an apology:  I'm bad with AJAX.  I'm trying to learn, but this particular project is giving me an absolute headache. I've read through a lot of examples, but can't find anything that helps with this issue.

**PROBLEM:** Using an "old-fashioned" PHP/MySQL/HTML environment, I'm trying to send data from a simple HTML form using AJAX; send the ajax request to php for updating a record in a MySQL db.  Unfortunately, my code just does not work.  It seems that I am effectively sending data, but somewhere in all of this I am coming up short.  **NOTE**:  I've confirmed that there is no problem with my Database connection, I use "$db" when inputting my name, password, db_name as indicated in my "show_client.php" file.

**MY GOAL**: I'm hoping to: 
(a) Update the existing variable using this AJAX request (no refresh of page); AND
(b) Display output in the div titled "case_activity_id2" after the form database row is updated and my ajax request has been submitted.

I have two relevant files:  (1) index.php; and (2) show_client.php.

index.php

```
<html>
  <td>
        <form id= "ajaxForm" action = ""  method = "POST" >
            <input type = "hidden" name='case_activity_id' id = 'case_activity_id' value = '<?php echo $case_activity_id?>'>
            <select name ='show_client_id' id = 'show_client_id' class="form-control">
                    <?php 
                        showClient();
                    ?> 
            </select>

  </td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="send" id = "btnClick" class="btn btn-primary" /> </form></td>
  <td><div id = "case_activity_id2"></div></td>

<script>

(function(){
    $("#btnClick").on("click", function(){ submitForm();});
})();
function submitForm(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ajaxForm").submit(function(event){
            var case_activity_id = $("#case_activity_id").val();
            var show_client_id = $("#show_client_id").val();
           $.ajax( {
              type: "POST",
              url:'show_client.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {
                    case_activity_id:case_activity_id, 
                    show_client_id:show_client_id
                    },
              success:function(data) {
                $('#case_activity_id2').html(data);
                console.log(data);
              }
           });
        });
    });
}
</script>
</html>
```

(2) show_client.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require 'db/connect.php';

            $show_client_id = $_POST['show_client_id']; 
            $case_activity_id = $_POST['case_activity_id']; 

            $sql = "UPDATE case_activity
                    SET show_client_id = '$show_client_id'
                    WHERE case_activity_id = '$case_activity_id'";  
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);  

?>
```

Comment: You don't return anything from your PHP script. What is this data you're trying to display after the update supposed to be?

Comment: show_client_id = “x” and case_activity_id = y

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. What possible data could you expect to be returned after a db update?

Comment: Okay sorry.  Let's not focus on "returning" any data back to the "div."  Any chance you can guide me on how to get the data from the form to the PHP request?

Comment: The `.submit` function doesn't actually submit the form, it only binds an event listener to the form. All you need inside your script are the contents of your `submitForm()` function (not the function itself - just the contents, place them directly in the script and delete everything else). Inside `.submit()` add `event.preventDefault()` to stop the page from redirecting (at the top of the handler, it needs to be the first thing).

Comment: El_Vanja is the man!!!! Thank you!

Comment: El_Vanja big question though....my call only works for the first record in a two record table...any reason why that may be happening?

Comment: Sounds like your html elements are using same ids. Ids need to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple once @el_vanja helped me out!  Thank you so much!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ajaxForm").submit(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var case_activity_id = $("#case_activity_id").val();
            var show_client_id = $("#show_client_id").val();
           $.ajax( {
              type: "POST",
              url:'show_client.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              data:
                    {
                        case_activity_id:case_activity_id, 
                        show_client_id:show_client_id
                    }, 
              success:function(data) {
               // $('#case_activity_id2').html(data);
                console.log(data);
              }
           });
        });
    });
```